# Rails 6 Rspec throws "ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError" on Carrierwave uploader

Tags: carrierwave, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I've got a FactoryBot factory that is erroring after upgrading to Rails 6. The error is:

```
Failure/Error: let(:lodge) { FactoryBot.create(:lodge) }

     ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
       can't write unknown attribute `checklist`
```

`Checklist` is an uploader (Carrierwave) on `Lodge`, mounted via the model, with permitted params for the field and `checklist_cache`.

I have run db:test:prepare, and the field exists in the test database (`Lodge.checklist` is a string).

The factory in question:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :lodge do
    name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    number { Faker::Number.number(digits: 3) }
    designator { Faker::Lorem.characters(number: 1) }
    combined { "999A" }
    status { "active" }
    association :council
    checklist { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec/support/lodge-checklist.pdf'), 'application/pdf') }
  end

end
```

The error persists whether or not I have the checklist line present.

Ruby 2.6.3; Rails 6.0.0, Carrierwave 2.0.0 (also occuring on master branch)

Comment: Further research: This only occurs when the uploader is mounted in a concern that is included on that model. If the uploader is called directly in the model RB file, it runs clean.

Answer (score 0):

This apparently was caused by the uploader being in the `included` block on a concern used by a variety of shared objects. Moving it back to the model alone fixed the problem.